# Can't get Simple form with custom wrapper to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to create custom wrappers to Simple Form, but I cannot get it to work as I want,
this is what I have:

simple_form_bootsrap.rb

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'control-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
    config.label_class = 'control-label'
    config.form_class = ''
    config.input_class = 'form-control'
    config.button_class = ''
  end

  config.wrappers :horizontal, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls col-sm-10' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
    config.label_class = 'col-sm-2 control-label'
    config.form_class = 'form-horizontal '
    config.input_class = 'form-control'
    config.button_class = 'btn btn-primary' 
  end
...
```

As you can see, I have created two wrappers, one called :horizontal and one called :bootstrap.

Now, in my code I call them in two different forms:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user :wrapper => :bootstrap) do |f| %>
```

And

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user,  :wrapper => :horizontal) do |f| %>
```

The last one, with :wrapper => :horizontal, works as intended. It gets all the classes and tags as I want.

But the first one, :wrapper => :bootstrap, uses the same setup as :horizontal. 
I want them to be separate, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: To me more precise, the config.* variables get inherited to all wrappers, how do I do specific config.* OR how do I only add a class to an element, without wrapping it inside another tag?

Comment: could you switch the order of definition and have a look if anything changes?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of what order i should change? Thanks